# How can I pass a variable into my custom database.yml on heroku for Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I need to pass variables that I have defined in my custom database.yml.  I am loading a database.yml to be used instead of the one that heroku overwrites with.

This variable is determined and assigned in my envirionments/production.rb file.

But I can't seem to get it to assign correctly.  It works if I hand-code it, but I cannot do that.

Help?

Comment: You cannot do that using database.yml. Wht don't you use custom created yml file, or just application.yml?

Comment: I created a custom .yml, I called it something else it seems to work -- I didn't realize I needed to use <%= %> erb in it...seems to work now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works to put in  tags from an environment

Answer (score 2):

Try following [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Sample_document):

```
---
variable: &myvar test
something: *myvar
```

Unfortunately, you cannot join normal string with a variable.